future simple vs future perfect
When the children wash their hands, they'll have lunch.
When the children have washed their hands, they’ll have lunch.
Are future simple and future perfect interchangeable in the above examples?

More or less, but with present simple we would be likely to say "After the children wash their hands, they'll have lunch."  Seems like a lot of learners aren't being taught about "before", "after", and "while", since so many questions use when in situations when those others would be better.

Thank you for the response. Seems that some English tests on the web are full of mistakes. The above sentences are from one

It could depend on the context. I can think of several possible contexts which alter the meaning slightly: 1) the children may not have lunch until they wash their hands. In this case, the first version is a bit better. 2) Plans are being made for a future event. In this case, the second is better. 3) The hand-washing is happening right now. In this case the first one isn't even an idiomatic choice; "when they're done washing" would be better.

The second sentence below is gibberish: When the children wash their hands, they often neglect to wash their thumbs.  When the children have washed their hands, they often neglect to wash their thumbs.

Yes, they are understood to have the same meaning ("immediately after washing their hands, the children will have lunch"), but this is clear not mainly because of grammar but because of the meaning: It's difficult or unusual to have lunch while washing your hands. In other cases, "when" might not convey "after" so clearly: "When you heat the water, it will boil" -> the boiling happens during the heating.
While the order of events is clear, depending on context the specific meaning could change, and one or the other wording could be more idiomatic. I can think of several possible contextual meanings:

The children may not have lunch until they wash their hands. In this case, the first version is a bit better.
Plans are being made for a future event. In this case, the second is better.
The hand-washing is happening right now. In this case the first one isn't even an idiomatic choice; "when they're done washing" would be better.


Thank you for the response. You are absolutely right. Sometimes it is difficult to figure out if "when" conveys "after" so clearly.

It's not a matter of "figuring out" that when is intended to mean "after" by that rather clumsy speaker.  If the meaning you want to convey is "after", say "after".

You are right, TimR. Thank you very much for your help. I greatly appreciate it.
